# google analytics bootstrap page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-analytics

I have inserted the google universal tracking code into my index.html based on Bootstrap Framework. It's like the following. However, in my Google analytics account it says the code was not installed. Anything wrong?

```
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-3018197-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Sometimes it takes Google Analytics a couple of hours to pick up on your code if you've just set it up

Comment: Can you see the code when you view source of your rendered html page?

Comment: Yes, I can see the code.

Comment: And in the source, I see the same code as above. If I go to google analytics account and it says: Status: Tracking Not Installed
Last checked: Mar 24, 2015 4:52:26 PM PDT
The Google Analytics tracking code has not been detected on your website's home page. For Analytics to function, you or your web administrator must add the code to each page of your website.
Learn more

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Nope. I don't see any error in the console. And I am using Chrome. Once I clicked "Inspect Element" --> Source, I can even see www.google-analytics.com listed. Does this mean it's working?

Comment: Oh, wait a sec. It's working now. I can see some analytics update on the dashboard. However, after I log into Google Analytics admin and check on the tracking code, the status still says Status: Tracking Not Installed
Last checked: Mar 24, 2015 5:52:12 PM PDT. Pretty weird.